# Нужна ли правка?

Tags: пунктуация, лексика

Москва. Какой она была, есть и будет. Какой её видит пешеход, водитель, турист, чиновник...

Comment: Правка корректорская или литературная?

Comment: Главное — ей вряд ли воспользуются. Этими словами начинается воскресная передача «Москвоведение (16+)» на ГОВОРИТ МОСКВА.

Answer (score 4):

Думаю, что правка небольшая всё-таки нужна.

Москва, какая она есть. Какой была и будет. Какой её видит пешеход, водитель, турист, чиновник...

Нельзя сказать "какой она есть".

Comment: Изменена последовательность, но связка «была-будет» вполне компенсирует.